# CSS: How to center a bottom-fixed menu

Tags: css

I've made a menu strip that I would like fixed to the bottom center of the page. I've tried everything. Is there a way to do this in CSS? I've gotten the menu to be fixed at the bottom of the page with

bottom: 0px 
position: fixed

but using

margin: auto auto 0px auto or margin-left: auto

doesn't seem to center the menu. It's just stuck to the left side of the page. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To center an element you need to specify width and set left and right margins to auto.
Then to stick such an element to the bottom of the page you need to wrap it in another element which has fixed width, say 100% and is positioned on the bottom. And yes, css you can.

```
<section style="position: fixed; bottom: 0px; width: 100%;">
 <p style="margin: 0 auto; width: 300px;">Blah blah</p>
</section>
```

Comment: Actually, this worked a bit better with the rest of my page. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

`display: flex` now makes this very easy! See below:

```css
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.content {
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <div class="content">My bottom-fixed content</div>
</div>
```

With this solution, there is no need to set a fixed width which can be more flexible.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a left property of 50% and a negative left margin equal to half the width of the footer.

http://jsfiddle.net/N7MB5/

```
#footer {
    width: 600px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -300px;
}
```

Comment: Ah! I knew it was something simple. Thank you!

Comment: And now.. You may also use left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%); if width not defined.

Answer (score 1):

```
#myElemId {
    width: 100px;
}
```

Note the fixed width; this is essential for `margin: auto` to work. If this doesn't solve it, then there must be a problem elsewhere.

Edit: You'll also need this (jQuery):

```
$("#myElemId").css({
    left: window.innerWidth/2 - $(this).css("width")/2
});
```

This allows you to set the width to whatever you want without having to update the rest of the CSS code.

Comment: This doesn't work for fixed positioned elements as they are out of the typical flow of the page.

Comment: Mm, of course. Updating to reflect, that's what you get for posting too fast.

Comment: Hehe, its always a race on SO. At least at night it slows down a bit.